# Retrieving multiple results from a query in PHP

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, mysqli

I am creating a script where I need to retrieve several information in a database. I am expecting to receive these datas

[image]

I need to get those 2 track paths. but  all I get is the first result and that's it.
I've run my SQL script in phpmyadmin it is completely showing all of the datas that I needed. but when I execute that query in PHP. it only returns to me the first result.
Here's my script

```
public static function find_user_tracks($id){
    global $mySQL;
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `tracks` WHERE account_id = {$id}";
    $result_set =  $mySQL->query($sql);
    return $result_set->fetch_assoc();
}
```

And here's the code I call to print the results

```
$row = Track::find_user_tracks($id);
                echo "{$row['track_path']}<br>";
```

but all I receive is only the first path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do a loop to return all records.

```
public static function find_user_tracks($id){
    global $mySQL;
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `tracks` WHERE account_id = {$id}";
    $result_set =  $mySQL->query($sql);
    $ret = array();
    while($row = $result_set->fetch_assoc()) {
      $ret[] = $row;
    }
    return $ret;
}
```

Comment: it only returns me an empty array. even though my query is correct.

Comment: @user962206 Are you sure? If `return $result_set->fetch_assoc();` will return you one record? How can this one return empty? :)

Comment: @user962206 Remember you also need to do a loop to print the results.